# Can't Output Anything from WordPress AJAX, no Errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an issue with Ajax in WordPress, I viewed 1000 posts about AJAX for a WordPress, but nothing. Everything seems ok.
I have a button with data-id attribute for every post on my index page, inside data-id I have its post id.
So idea is simple when someone click on this button I want to create a `div` with text, which will be post id. But I get nothing, I haven't any error, in my console everything is ok, but div is not created.

**My enqueue scripts:**

```
function _themename_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script( '_themename-dummy-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/js/ajax.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script('_themename-dummy-scripts', 'viasun_dummy_ajax', array(
        'ajax_url'       => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '_themename_assets');
```

**My JS:**

```
$('.c-post__button a').on( 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this);
    var id = button.data('id');

    var data = {
        id: id,
        action: "viasun_dummy_ajax_data_action"
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        url: viasun_dummy_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function( ) {
            console.log("sending");
        },
        success: function(message) {
            if( data ) {
                $("body").append(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("error");
        }
    } );
});
```

**My action for ajax:**

```
function viasun_dummy_ajax_data_action(){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo '<div class="id-container">' . $id . '</div>';
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_viasun_dummy_ajax_data_action', 'viasun_dummy_ajax_data_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_viasun_dummy_ajax_data_action', 'viasun_dummy_ajax_data_action' );
```

**In my console from js I get:**

```
Object { id: 15, action: "viasun_dummy_ajax_data_action" }
```

And XHR in console says `200 OK`.
What am I doing wrong? Can you help me, please?

Comment: why are you appending the Object `data ` and not the `message`?

Comment: @epascarello OMG! That was a problem, lol. I've been suffering for a week. Write your answer and I will mark it. Thanks a lot!